# Relabel external ID

Tags: contacts

is there a way to relabel `external id`? I want to use it but set it for our client in a way they are used to.
I've tried Word Replacement but it seemed ineffective.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External ID can be replaced with word replacement but it has to be done directly with the original English chain 'External ID' and not its translation that I wanted to replace again.

Something like 'External ID' >> 'Code fédéral'

Thanks to @aydun on Mattermost

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a buildForm hook if you want to, or by customizing a template (see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/customizing/)

You can also do it with the Contact Layout Editor extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor).